# How can I apply Unmarshaller to HttpRequest->HttpResponse flow

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I use the akka framework in my java project for working with HTTP services, that's why I use javaDSL for working with akka streams. So, the my story below.
I created http cached pool (in my actor):

```
val pool = Http.get(getContext().system()).cachedHostConnectionPool(
            "https://somehost.com",
            ActorMaterializer.create(getContext().system())
    )
```

Then I created a source based on HttpRequest:

```
val source = Source.single(HttpRequest.GET("/resources/123/"))
```

And then I created unmarshaller for converting HttpReponse to exact Entity:

```
val unmarshaller = Jackson.unmarshaller(objectMapper, ResourceEntity.class)
```

The next step was pass the source via pool to handle response in my actor:

```
source.via(pool)
      // TODO: unmarshalling
      .to(Sink.actorRef(getSelf(), new FlowCompletedMessage()))
      .run(ActorMaterializer.create(getContext().system()));
```

The question is how can apply unmarshaller to this flow? I did not find any examples, and I feel myself like a child which is trying to shove square figure into round hole...

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
source.via(pool)
      .mapAsync(response => Unmarshal(response).to[T])
      .to(Sink.actorRef(getSelf(), new FlowCompletedMessage()))
      .run(ActorMaterializer.create(getContext().system()));
```

Comment: There is no Unmarshal class in JavaDSL. Even, if I will use scaladsl, Unmarshal.to method requires ExecutionContexts and Meterializer additionaly to Marashler. And why are you suggest to use mapAsync?